# Maven - How to Install/Deploy timestamped SNAPSHOTS

Tags: java, maven

Env : `Maven 3.3.9`

Hi,

I have a maven jar module with version as 1.0-SNAPSHOT. When i do `mvn install`, the jar installed into local repository (`~/.m2/repository`) does not have timestamp. I agree that its not a common scenario where you would like to have timestamped jars in your `~/.m2/repository` repo. But still couple of questions:

1. Does `mvn install` append timestamp automatically? Looking for some
   configuration way rather than use `${timestamp}` in final name.
2. Does automatic timestamp mechanism applies to `mvn deploy`?
3. Is there a way to tell maven to use `~/.m2/repository`
   itself for `mvn deploy`?

Thanks,

Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

The `mvn install` will only put your project into your local cache which means it makes it available for other projects on your machine.

`mvn deploy` will deploy the artifacts into your remote repository which is usually a corporate repository manager.

In case of a `SNAPSHOT` this means this artifact has not been finalized and is under developer. This means you can create several states of the same version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. The time stamp which is created during the deployment to a repository manager is intended to have different artifacts available for development. You can control via `-U` option if you like to use the most recent version of the SNAPSHOT's.

After you feel ready you make a so called release which will set the version to something like `1.0.0` (without SNAPSHOT) which is deployed as well but into a release repository which is immutable.

Furthermore having timestamps in your local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` does not make really sense, cause you can control when you install an artifact there and no one else and you should prevent using `finalName` change cause this is only intended for your `target` folder and not for your local cache.
And finally using the local cache for `mvn deploy` does not make sense, cause what is the idea behind that? Best is to start using a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva in particular if your are working in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @khmarbaise's answer see the following references:

- [Maven / Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html):

  > There are strictly only two types of repositories: local and remote. The local repository refers to a copy on your own installation that is a cache of the remote downloads, and also contains the temporary build artifacts that you have not yet released.
  >
  > Remote repositories refer to any other type of repository, [...]
- [Maven: The Complete Reference, 15.2.8. Repositories](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/appendix-settings-sect-details.html#appendix-settings-sect-settings-repository):

  > Repositories are remote collections of projects from which Maven uses to populate the local repository of the build system.
- [Repository - SNAPSHOT Handling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+-+SNAPSHOT+Handling) reads:

  > This documentation was targetted at Maven 2.0 alpha 1. It is here only for historical reference and to be updated and integrated into the Maven documentation.

  But I didn't find any latest documentation where this has been integrated. (@khmarbaise?)

  > Timestamped files are not created on install in the local repository for reasons of disk space preservation. However, when a SNAPSHOT is resolved and downloaded, it is saved with its timestamp version number (eg: 0.15-20050401.150432-2).
- [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm)
- [Maven Dependency Resolution - A Repository Perspective](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/12/maven-dependency-resolution-a-repository-perspective/)

Long story short:

The same snapshot version can be deployed to a *remote repository* from different hosts, so they have to be distinguished there somehow. And they are distinguished by timestamps (and a build number).

There will be an artifact with a timestamp (and build number) in the *local repository* only if Maven resolved and, hence, downloaded it from remote.

So:

1. No.
2. Yes.
3. Would break Maven's repositories handling of *local* vs. *remote*.

Comment: @khmarbaise Are you aware of where [Repository - SNAPSHOT Handling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+-+SNAPSHOT+Handling) is integrated or can you do it?